# Replace empty object, mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb

I'm down to this after some aggregation piping:

```
[
  {},
  {
    "city": "Falun"
  },
  {
    "city": "Gävle"
  }
]
```

How can I go from this to this:

```
   [
      {
        "city": "N/A"
      },
      {
        "city": "Falun"
      },
      {
        "city": "Gävle"
      }
    ]
```

Comment: please add some sample documents and the pipeline your using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this step at the end of your pipeline should help

```
$project: {
    city: { $ifNull: [ "$city", "N/A" ] }
}
```